# WriteFile and WriteConsole

Tags: c, winapi

I want to be able to use `WriteFile` or `WriteConsole` so the following 3 functions work:

```
> Output.exe
> Output.exe > File.txt & type File.txt
> for /F "tokens=*" %A in ('Output.exe') do @echo %A
```

I managed to get the first two working with my current code. But now the for loop outputs: `The system cannot write to the specified device.`

I guess it doesn't like my BOM. **How can I make my code work with the for loop?**

Here's my current code.

```
DWORD   dwBytesWritten;
DWORD   dwConMode;
BOOL    bRedirectedToFile;
WCHAR   str[] = L"Hello World";

bRedirectedToFile = !GetConsoleMode(hStdOut, &dwConMode);

if (bRedirectedToFile)
{
    LONG  zero = 0;
    DWORD pos  = SetFilePointer(hStdOut, 0, &zero, FILE_CURRENT);

    if (pos == 0)
    {
        WORD Unicode = ((BYTE*)L"A")[0] == 0 ? 0xfffe : 0xfeff;
        WriteFile(hStdOut, &Unicode, 2, &dwBytesWritten, 0);
    }

    WriteFile(hStdOut, str, lstrlen(str) * sizeof(WCHAR), &dwBytesWritten, 0);
}
else
{
    WriteConsole(hStdOut, str, lstrlen(str), &dwBytesWritten, 0);
}
```

Comment: Do you know why it fails? That is, do you know if `bRedirectedToFile` is returning an unexpected value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the output of `wprintf` which seems to convert the string to ASCII before printing it.

So current acceptable solution:

1. Convert `str` to ASCII
2. Print `str` with WriteFile

Much simpler code too.